# Benefits from object as string specified as own object index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was examining the code from MongoDB's `runCommand` method, for my education:

```
function ( obj, extra ){
    if ( typeof( obj ) == "string" ){
        var n = {};
        n[obj] = 1;
        obj = n;
        if ( extra && typeof( extra ) == "object" ) {
            for ( var x in extra ) {
                n[x] = extra[x];
            }
        }
    }
    return this.getCollection( "$cmd" ).findOne( obj );
}
```

I focused on this chunk:

```
var n = {};
n[obj] = 1;
obj = n;
```

Now, the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) says about the method:

> A database command, specified either in document form or as a string. If specified as a string, db.runCommand() transforms the string into a document.

Although this explains the third line in short, I am trying to find out what the developers were thinking about this one:

```
n[obj] = 1;
```

My thought about benefits from this is that this can be used for equality purposes on the object maybe on an inner call, where doing:

```
var checkEq = n["{num: 1}"];
```

Would return the "truey" 1, especially useful for fast and clean equality check, but any insight/assurance of a more experienced developer about cases of this trick being useful would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `n[obj] = 1;` is being used to normalize the command that is passed in. We can see in the documentation for [issue-commands](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/#issue-commands), that all of their example commands are of the form `runCommand({command: 1})`. For example, if someone used `runCommand("buildInfo")` then the string `"buildInfo"` would be transformed into the object `{"buildInfo": 1}`.

Why they use this object notation with the key being the command and the value being one is beyond me. I combed though the documentation and code for a reason for the value to be one, but my search ended up empty handed.